# Partitioning Mac Catalina SSD drive in order to dual boot Ubuntu

Tags: catalina, unix, dual-boot

I'm trying to partition my Mac Catalina hard drive in order to dual boot Ubuntu. Everything is set up for the install except the partition. All the guides that I read say to partition the internal ssd drive in the disk utility application. But when I try to add a new partition in the add partition tab, it says

"This container has 30 GB used space.
Its minimum size is 120 GB.
This container can’t be split, because the resulting containers would be too small."

any advice?

Comment: Why not just run Ubuntu from a virtual machine?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. Is it more common than a dual boot?

Comment: Unless there is an explicit need to have Ubuntu running directly on physical hardware I'd run it in a virtual machine so no dual booting, run the Host and Guest OSes at the same time. In my experience Linux runs better in a VM then a physical install on a Mac. It just really depends on what your needs are. You can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) , which is free, or [VMware Fusion Player](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html) which is free for personal use, or Parallels Desktop for Mac, which is a paid product. (Personally I use VMware Fusion Pro.)